# How to call completion handler in list item in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have list with item in which I have one more list. Here is list item:

```
struct CohortItemView:View {
    @State var cohortsGetter: ProfilesInCohort
    let cohortItem:CohortArrayItem
    @ObservedObject var profilesGetter = CohortProcessor()
    
    init(item:CohortArrayItem) {
        self.cohortItem = item
        self.cohortsGetter = ProfilesInCohort.init(cohortWebId: cohortItem.cohort?.webID ?? "")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text(cohortItem.cohort?.name ?? "no data")
                    .padding(.leading,10)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                Spacer()
                
                ZStack{
                    Text("Show all \(cohortItem.profilesNum!)")
                }.padding(.trailing,10)
            }
            
            
            var usersInCohort { array in
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack{
                        ForEach(1..<6, id: \.self) {
                            let user = (array![$0].profile)
                            UserCard(user: UserModel(name: user.firstName ?? "", position: user.lastName ?? "", image: "moon.stars.fill"))
                        }
                    }.padding(10)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func usersInCohort(completion:@escaping ([ProfilesInCohortModel.ProfilesArrayItem]?)->Void) {
        let params = ["offset":6,"cohortWebID":cohortItem.cohort?.webID ?? ""] as [String : Any]
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "url")!)
        request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
        request.httpBody =  try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        
        AF.request(request).responseDecodable(of: ProfilesInCohortModel.self) { (response) in
            if response.response?.statusCode == 200{
                completion(response.value?.profiles)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see I have list in list item. And I would like to show list after showing list item. Here is this child list item:

```
struct UserCard: View {
    let user:UserModel
    init(user:UserModel) {
        self.user = user
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                Image(systemName: user.image)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 64.0, height: 64.0)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .shadow(radius: 10)
                Button(action: {
                    print("Edit button was tapped")
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: user.image)
                }
            }
            Text(user.name)
                .fontWeight(.regular)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Text(user.position)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

but in this code block:

```
var usersInCohort { array in
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack{
                        ForEach(1..<6, id: \.self) {
                            let user = (array![$0].profile)
                            UserCard(user: UserModel(name: user.firstName ?? "", position: user.lastName ?? "", image: "moon.stars.fill"))
                        }
                    }.padding(10)
                }
            }
```

in this line:

```
var usersInCohort { array in
```

I have such error:

```
Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'
```

I don't understand why it is happening.I tried to use also observed object, and it also didn't help me. As a result I would like to see lists inside parent list item. Maybe I did smth wrong?

### UPDATE

my models:

```
struct ProfilesInCohortModel:Decodable {
    var num,status:Int?
    var noMore,authRequired:Bool?
    var profiles:[ProfilesArrayItem]?
    
    enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey {
        case num,status,authRequired,profiles
        case noMore = "flagNoMore"
    }
    
    
    struct ProfilesArrayItem:Decodable{
        let profile:ProfileItem
        let publiclyForwarded:Int
        let altCohort:CohortItem
        
        enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey {
            case profile,altCohort
            case publiclyForwarded = "followedBySessionUser_publicly"
        }
    }
    
    struct ProfileItem:Decodable,Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let inode,superSedByNode,status,createdUser,editedUser:Int?
        let webID,notes,web,wikipedia,suffix,bio,title:String?
        let name,akaName,firstName,middleName,lastName,fullName:String?
        let twitter,linkedin,instagram,github,email,phone:String?
        let createTime,lastEditTime:UInt64?
        let hasImage:Bool?
        
        enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey {
            case inode,webID,name,akaName,firstName,middleName,lastName,fullName
            case notes,web,wikipedia,twitter,linkedin,instagram,github,phone
            case status,suffix,bio,title
            case editedUser = "user_lastedit"
            case createdUser = "user_created"
            case superSedByNode = "superseded_by_node"
            case email = "contact_email"
            case createTime = "time_created"
            case lastEditTime = "time_lastedit"
            case hasImage =  "has_image"
        }
        
    }
}
```

and:

```
struct UserModel {
    var name:String
    var position:String
    var image:String
}
```

Comment: @matt, and how I can solve this problem? maybe we have some another solution?

Comment: I tried observable obj but data downloaded only for several parent list items, so I thought that I did smth wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd move your async code to a view model. Then, use `onAppear` to call the async method to retrieve the cohorts. Then, you can use `ForEach` on the result stored in a `Published` variable:

```
class CohortRetriever : ObservableObject {
    @Published var retrievedCohorts: [ProfilesInCohortModel.ProfilesArrayItem] = []
    
    func retrieve(cohortItem: CohortArrayItem) {
        self.usersInCohort(cohortItem: cohortItem) { result in
            self.retrievedCohorts = result
        }
    }
    
    private func usersInCohort(cohortItem: CohortArrayItem, completion:@escaping ([ProfilesInCohortModel.ProfilesArrayItem]?)->Void) {
        let params = ["offset":6,"cohortWebID":cohortItem.cohort?.webID ?? ""] as [String : Any]
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "url")!)
        request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
        request.httpBody =  try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        
        AF.request(request).responseDecodable(of: ProfilesInCohortModel.self) { (response) in
            if response.response?.statusCode == 200{
                completion(response.value?.profiles)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CohortItemView:View {
    @State var cohortsGetter: ProfilesInCohort
    let cohortItem:CohortArrayItem
    @ObservedObject var profilesGetter = CohortProcessor()
    
    @StateObject var retriever = CohortRetriever()
    
    init(item:CohortArrayItem) {
        self.cohortItem = item
        self.cohortsGetter = ProfilesInCohort.init(cohortWebId: cohortItem.cohort?.webID ?? "")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text(cohortItem.cohort?.name ?? "no data")
                    .padding(.leading,10)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                Spacer()
                
                ZStack{
                    Text("Show all \(cohortItem.profilesNum!)")
                }.padding(.trailing,10)
            }
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack{
                    ForEach(retriever.retrievedCohorts) { user in //<-- Here
                        UserCard(user: UserModel(name: user.firstName ?? "", position: user.lastName ?? "", image: "moon.stars.fill"))
                    }
                }.padding(10)
            }
        }.onAppear { //<-- Here
            self.retriever.retrieve(cohortItem: cohortItem)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I don't have all of your code, so there may be minor issues, like if your model doesn't conform to `Hashable`, you may have to pass an `id:` to `ForEach`.

Also, you could refactor `retrieve` to be *one* function without a callback -- you can see that I've wrapped `usersInCohort`. But, that's just busywork that you could do if you're interested.

Lastly, I'm not too sure what `CohortProcessor` does in your code -- it's initialized and then never used. Perhaps that code should be combined with my idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after adding your code and correcting all data due to the models, I received such error `Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project` with foreach code block :(

Comment: Like I said, I don't have all of your code. My suspicion is you'll need to add an `id` for the `ForEach`. Can you update your question with your `ProfilesInCohortModel.ProfilesArrayItem` and `UserModel` code so I can see if they're `Hashable` or `Identifiable`?

Comment: just a second, I will add them

Comment: I have just added them

Comment: Try replacing my `ForEach` line with `ForEach(retriever.retrievedCohorts.map { $0.profile }, id: \.id) { user in`

Comment: yes, I have managed to run the app, but I saw only 5 of 10 parent items with children lists, maybe we have to add sleep for pause between loading and showing?

Comment: hm... as I see I received 500 server error for items which don't have any child lists, so as I see you solved my problem, Thank you very much 